# How to work with more elements with same class in one page using Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

so basically i am making a program in Python that is going to go to one site, click on one picture (than do something) and than move to another picture (and do the same thing) and so on.. well the problem is, there is like 10 pictures with same `img` class BUT `scr` is always changing and i hope that could help me.. so now my code opens one image and it does its job but once it's finished instead of moving to another image(element) with same class it opens the same picture and makes a loop which i don't want..

Comment: src* not scr :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use x-path, I'm using a chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph?hl=en

To locate the picture.

And then you can use driver.find_element_by_xpath("X-PATH")